# adding order by to select command from webconfig

Tags: asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

Hello I have an sql data source (below) and the select command is in the webconfig it is a simple select...from... . I use this select command a few times but the ORDER BY changes. Is there anyway to write something like `"<%$ AppSettings:SelectCustomer %>"` & `ORDER BY CUST_NAME`. I tried a few ways moving the & and " around but no luck. Any suggestions?

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dataSourceCBCust" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString = "<%$ ConnectionStrings:Customer %>"
        ProviderName = "<%$ ConnectionStrings:Customer.ProviderName %>"
        SelectCommand = "<%$ AppSettings:SelectCustomer %>" >
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Do it in code behind; it will be much easier to concatenate that way.